# Error of weigted average of elements with errors

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-error, mean, error-propagation

I have a set of data with errorbars ($x_i, \sigma_i$), and I need to compute a weigted average and the error. I used the formulas from https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Leo/Stats4_5.html

For the weigted average : $$ \mu = \frac{\Sigma x_i \sigma_i^{-2}}{\Sigma \sigma_i^{-2}}$$

But for the error :  $$ \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\Sigma \sigma_i^{-2}}}$$ (56) 
The problem is that the value of the mean error because is not taking in account the scattering of the points, which is bigger than errorbars.

Is there a formula that takes in account both errorbars of individual points and scattering between them ?